# Creating CRUD form for the list of addresses using template driven model

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to create a form to generate below structure using template driven model.

```
{name: 'Raymond',
address [{street:'permanent'},{street:'temporary'}]
}
```

but when i use [(ngModel)]="address[index].street". It is generating in below format.

```
{name:'Raymond',
address[0].street:'permanent',
address[1].street:'temporary'
}
```

Where m i doing the mistake?

Comment: Using a template driven form and creating an array is not possible without hacking. I suggest you use a reactive form where you can easily use a formarray for this :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally created using reactive form control